# Submit Data from partial view to a controller post function MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, partial-views

I have one partial view to create new data, and one parent view (list data). If I am trying to create new data and clicking the submit button. The data from the partial view not going to the controller (post function).

Below my controller code:

```
public class TourSettingsController : Controller 
{
    [httppost]
    public ActionResult _tourTypeCreate(TourType model,string tourtypeID)
    {
        return partialview(model)
    }
}
```

Partial view:

[image]

Parent view:

[image]

Comment: How is look like your view ?

Comment: The partial view witch displays the data have the model of the type tourtype? Is it displaying the data from the model received?

Comment: could please check my partial view and parent view image

Comment: Try adding hidden field TourTypeId in partial view. It might be available in parent but not partial view.

Comment: thank you i solved that problem, i used button type .that's why data from partial view not coming to controller(httppost). i used (<input type=submit id=btnSave value=Save/>